# Bypass parse_ini_file reserved words

Tags: php

I have this code (not made by me):

Inside of the file: Something=

I want to make it Something=false

```
$filename = 'server.properties';

$data = parse_ini_file($filename);

$replace_with = array(
   'Something' => false
);

$fh = fopen($filename, 'w');

foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
{

  if ( ! empty($replace_with[$key]) )
    $value = $replace_with[$key];


  fwrite($fh, "{$key}={$value}" . PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($fh);
}
```

The output should be Something=false to server.properties.
But the false is a reserved word in php parse_ini_file.

(Note:  There are reserved words which must not be used as keys for ini files. These include: null, yes, no, true, false, on, off, none. Values null, no and false results in "", yes and true results in "1". Characters ?{}|&~![()^" must not be used anywhere in the key and have a special meaning in the value.)

Problem is I have done a long code with it and as it turns out I can't use false nor 0. Therefore is there a way to still send the word "false" in the array? Or is there a simple way to do this all differently?

Comment: Why don't you write the string `'false'` instead of the predefined constant `false`?  It's all being written as a string anyway.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Already tried 'false' and it did not work.

Comment: Explain "*did not work*".  If you print the value of `{$key}={$value}`, what do you get?  Are you sure you did `'false'` and not `"false"`?

Comment: @BLaZuRE If you mean    'Something' => 'false'  then that's what I did and tried.

Comment: put `if ($value === false) $value = "false";` before `fwrite`

Comment: @BLaZuRE Doesn't seems to be working.
Hopefully did as you said.
foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
{

  if ( ! empty($replace_with[$key]) )
    $value = $replace_with[$key];

if ($value === false) $value = "false";
  fwrite($fh, "{$key}={$value}" . PHP_EOL);
}